# Select get entire row corresponding to max in MySQL Group

Tags: mysql

When I use `Max` to find the maximum value of a field in a particular MySQL Group after using `GROUP BY`, is it possible to get the entire row which contains the maximum value?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this thread when working on some forum code. I wanted to get the latest post for each thread and display it in the list of threads for a particular board.

Quassnoi's answer above was very helpful to me and I was able to adapt it. Here is the code in case it helps anyone else:

```
SELECT p.id As post_id, p.post_number, p.topic_id
FROM forum_post p, (
    SELECT topic_id, MAX(post_number) As max_post_number
    FROM   forum_post d
    GROUP  BY topic_id) dd
WHERE p.id =
(
    SELECT id
    FROM   forum_post
    WHERE  topic_id = dd.topic_id
    AND    post_number = dd.max_post_number
    ORDER  BY topic_id DESC, post_number DESC, id DESC
    LIMIT  1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would work:

```
select * from table where id in (select distinct max(id) from table group by name)
```

Comment: You might get too many rows. Your statement returns all rows having an id which is the maximum of any group (not necessarily the group  this row belongs to). Consider the following (id,name) pairs: (1,foo), (2,foo), (2,bar), (3,bar). You want to retrieve (2,foo) and (3,bar), but your query also returns (2,bar) since 2 is the max of the foo-group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  di.id, di.orderer, di.ghigh, di.glow
FROM    (
        SELECT  glow, MIN(orderer) AS orderer
        FROM    t_distinct d
        GROUP BY
                glow
        ) dd
JOIN    t_distinct di
ON      di.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    t_distinct ds
        WHERE   ds.glow = dd.glow
                AND ds.orderer = dd.orderer
        ORDER BY
                glow DESC, orderer DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

See this article for more explanations:

- [**MySQL: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum (resolving ties)**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/25/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-resolving-ties/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following query:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items, (select @grouping_value:=null) as init
WHERE GREATEST(grouping_field=@grouping_value,
               IF(@grouping_value:=grouping_field,0,0))
ORDER BY grouping_field, sorted_field DESC
```

The idea is to sort table data by grouping field and sorted field and take the first row from each group