# Mysql, select max and match value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with dates and values.
What I'm trying to do is to get the MAX() value of values and the date that corresponds to that value.
i.e.

```
+------------+-------+
| pdate      | score |
+------------+-------+
| 2012-05-01 |    80 |
| 2012-05-02 |    50 |
| 2012-05-03 |    52 |
| 2012-04-02 |   100 |
| 2012-05-02 |    10 | 
+------------+-------+
```

The output that I want is  2012-04-02 - 100

This is my query:

```
SELECT pdate,MAX(Score) as maxscore FROM tblpulse 
 WHERE DID = '171488' && pdate BETWEEN '2012-05-02' 
   AND '2012-06-26' and pdate ORDER BY pdate ASC
```

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions in the related bar, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584481/select-get-entire-row-corresponding-to-max-in-mysql-group?rq=1

Comment: What's the DID column in your query?

Answer (score 2):

Create a subquery and sort by your MAX...

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT pdate,MAX(Score) as maxscore FROM tblpulse 
WHERE DID = '171488' && pdate BETWEEN '2012-05-02' 
AND '2012-06-26' and pdate ORDER BY pdate ASC)
ORDER BY maxscore DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select pdate, score
  from tblpulse
 where ... and pdate between '2012-05-02' and '2012-06-26'
   and score = ( select max( score ) from tblpulse where pdate between '2012-05-02' and '2012-06-26')
```

(I left out the DID thing because that column isn't described in the question.)